# Testing a select tag, angular js and jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I have this select box which filters when I change another select. Trying to write a e2e test.

This is my markup:

```
<select id="inputPipe" ng-model="selectedPipe" ng-options="p.title_en for p in pipes"></select>

<select id="inputSize" ng-model="selectedSize" ng-options="s.nominalsize for s in sizesFromPipes"></select>
```

So when I change the first select the second gets filtered.

This is my e2e test

```
select('selectedPipe').option('Steel');
```

Then I'm not sure how to continue.

This a pseudo code:

```
expect(<select>('sizesFromPipes[5].nominalsize').toBe('DN50')
```

How do I write the last one correct?

Answer (score -2):

Maybe it help you:

```
select('selectedPipe').option('Steel');
expect(input('selectedPipe').val()).toBe('0'); // key

select('selectedSize').option('DN50');
expect(input('selectedPipe').val()).toBe('1'); // key
```

I have in my app something like this:

HTML:

```
<select ng-model="filter.country" ng-options="c.name for c in countries"></select>
<select ng-model="filter.region" ng-options="r.name for r in filter.country.regions"></select>
```

JavaScript:

```
it('should filter on country and region select choose', function() {
  select('filter.country').option('Germany');
  // 0 because this is key of selected option
  expect(input('filter.country').val()).toBe('0');

  select('filter.region').option('Hesse');
  // 1 because this is key of selected option
  expect(input('filter.region').val()).toBe('1'); 
});
```

Comment: it's protractor not pure karma!